# Using an array of regex expressions for .match

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have something I am trying to accomplish.

I'd like to take an array built with AJAX/`xml`.

```
array[/word0/, /word1/, /word2/]
```

and put this into a form that could be used in a `.match()`:

```
result = string.match(array)
```

I have tried using a for loop and stepping through the array using `string.match(array[i])` to no avail.

Is there an easy way to do this?

Comment: `string.match(/word0|word1|word2/)`

Comment: What was the error you got? I think you'll have to be more descriptive than "to no avail". What you were doing is a valid solution, so my guess is your problem lies elsewhere (see my answer for a more specific guess).

Comment: I'm not actually getting any errors.  I understand the principle of using your example, however, if I dump the contents of the array prior to the .join I get "word1", "word2", "word3".  After the .join I get this:
/(?:)/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Edit:** You may have a syntax problem. The following is not valid syntax:

```
array[/word0/, /word1/, /word2/]
```

Something like this fixes it:

```
var regexps = [/word0/, /word1/, /word2/];
```

---

**Original answer:**

Javascript `RegExp`s already do this. You're looking for:

```
var regexp = /word0|word1|word2/;
```

Assuming your list of matches comes back in the right format, you could achieve this like so:

```
var words = ["word0", "word1", "word2"];
var regexp = new Regexp(words.join("|"));
str.match(regexp);
```

Comment: Thank you sir.  I did indeed have a syntax problem.  I had a } cutting off access the original array.  Although it took several hours you helped me track it down.  Also thanks to the others for the suggestions.  Cheers

Answer (score 1):

http://jsfiddle.net/KALPh/

Your approach was fine. Here's my implementation:

```
var regexes = [/^def/, /^abc/],
    testString = 'abcdef',
    numRegexes = regexes.length;

for(var x=0;x<numRegexes;x++) {
    alert(regexes[x].test(testString));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

To initialize your array, use

```
var array = [/word0/, /word1/, /word2/];
```

Then you can use

```
str.match(array[i])
```

If your problem is the transmission in "AJAX/xml", then you'll need to build the regular expressions client side with `new RegExp(somestring)` where `somestring` might for example be `"word0"` : you can't embed a regex **literal** in XML.

Comment: Sorry I guess I should have been more precise.  I just gave abridged code.